# Delete specific date records from table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to delete a specific date record from MYSQL table

Date insert in TIMESTAMP

i tried this query but not worked:

```
DELETE FROM `tracking` WHERE `track_time` = '2015-03-07'
```

Records in table are present in that time stap like

```
DELETE FROM `tracking` WHERE `track_time` = '2015-03-07'

2014-05-28 00:00:02
```

Let me know please

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM tracking WHERE date(track_time) = '2015-03-07'
```

or

```
DELETE FROM tracking 
WHERE track_time > '2015-03-07 00:00:02' and track_time < '2015-03-08 00:00:02'
```

Answer (score 1):

For [performance reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), if you have a large number of rows, and you have an index on `track_time`, consider the simple case of a range based filter, instead of applying functions like `date()` in the `where` predicate:

```
DELETE FROM tracking WHERE track_time >= '2015-03-07' AND track_time < '2015-03-08';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the date out of timestamp using `date` function as

```
DELETE FROM tracking WHERE date(track_time) = '2015-03-07'
```

Answer (score 0):

This may by the query you're looking for:

```
DELETE FROM tracking WHERE date(track_time) like '2015-03-07'
```

Let me know if that solve your problem.